# Merge axis in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I want to convert X,Y,Z numpy array to (X*Z)*Y numpy array.

Code(Slow):

```
 def rearrange(data):
        samples,channels,t_insts=data.shape
        append_data=np.empty([0,channels])
        for sample in range(0,samples):
            for t_inst in range(0,t_insts):
                channel_data=data[sample,:,t_inst]
                append_data=np.vstack((append_data,channel_data))
        return append_data.shape
```

I am looking for a better vectorized approach if possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) to swap `rows` with `columns` and then reshape -

```
data.transpose(0,2,1).reshape(-1,data.shape[1])
```

Or use [`np.swapaxes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) to do the swapping of rows and columns and then reshape -

```
data.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,data.shape[1])
```

Comment: Is there some more general method for this? Say I want to convert array of shape `(4,5,6,7,8,9)` to `(4,5*6*8,7,9)`

Comment: @Gulzar `a.transpose(0,1,2,4,3,5)` and then reshape to desired shape. Idea being - Bring the axes to be merged in sequence and then reshape. This could be a relevant post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/