# Intuition and idea behind reshaping 4D array to 2D array in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

While implementing a [`Kronecker-product`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Example) for *pedagogical reasons* (without using the obvious and readily available `np.kron()`), I obtained a 4 dimensional array as an intermediate result, which I've to reshape to get the final result.

But, I still can't wrap my head around reshaping these high dimensional arrays. I have this `4D` array:

```
array([[[[ 0,  0],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 5, 10],
         [15, 20]]],


       [[[ 6, 12],
         [18, 24]],

        [[ 7, 14],
         [21, 28]]]])
```

This is of shape `(2, 2, 2, 2)` and I'd like to reshape it to `(4,4)`. One might think that this is obvious to do with

```
np.reshape(my4darr, (4,4))
```

But, the above reshape *does not* give me the *expected result* which is:

```
array([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
       [ 6,  7, 12, 14],
       [ 0, 15,  0, 20],
       [18, 21, 24, 28]])
```

As you can see, all the elements in the *expected result* are present in the `4D` array. I just can't get the hang of doing the *reshape* correctly as needed. In addition to the answer, some explanation of how to do the `reshape` for such high dimensional arrays would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### General idea for `nd` to `nd` transformation

The idea with such `nd` to `nd` transformation is using just two things -

- Permute axes (with [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or [`numpy.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html#numpy.moveaxis) or [`numpy.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) if the needed permute order is a rolled one or [`numpy.swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) if just two axes need to be swapped) and
- Reshape.

**Permute axes :** To get the order such that the flattened version corresponds to the flattened version of output. So, if you somehow end up using it twice, look again because you shouldn't.

**Reshape :** To split the axes or bring the final output to the desired shape. Splitting axes is needed mostly at the start, when the input is of lower-dim and we are needed to split into blocks. Again, you shouldn't need this more than twice.

Hence, generally we would have three steps :

```
    [ Reshape ]      --->  [ Permute axes ]   --->  [ Reshape ]

 Create more axes             Bring axes             Merge axes
                          into correct order
```

**Back-tracking method**

The safest way to solve, given the input and output is through, what one could call as the back-tracking method, i.e. split the axes of the input (when going from smaller `nd` to bigger `nd`) or split the axes of the output (when going from bigger `nd` to smaller `nd`). The idea with the splitting is to bring the number of dims of the smaller `nd` one same as the bigger `nd` one. Then, study the strides of the output and match it up against the input to get the required permute order. Finally, a reshape (default way or C order) might be needed at the end, if the final one is a smaller `nd` one, to merge axes.

If both input and output are of same number of dims, then we would need to split both and break into blocks and study their strides against each other. In such cases, we should have the additional input parameter of block sizes, but that's probably off-topic.

#### Example

Let's use this specific case to demonstrate how to apply those strategies. In here, the input is `4D`, while output is `2D`. So, most probably, we won't need reshape to split. So, we need to start with permuting axes. Since, the final output is not `4D`, but a `2D` one, we would need a reshape at the end.

Now, the input here is :

```
In [270]: a
Out[270]: 
array([[[[ 0,  0],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 5, 10],
         [15, 20]]],


       [[[ 6, 12],
         [18, 24]],

        [[ 7, 14],
         [21, 28]]]])
```

The expected output is :

```
In [271]: out
    Out[271]: 
    array([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
           [ 6,  7, 12, 14],
           [ 0, 15,  0, 20],
           [18, 21, 24, 28]])
```

Also, this is a bigger `nd` to smaller `nd` transformation, so the back-tracking method would involve, splitting the output and studying its [strides](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) and matching up against the corresponding values in input :

```
                    axis = 3
                   ---      -->          
                                        
                    axis = 1                    
                   ------>           
axis=2|  axis=0|   [ 0,  5,  0, 10],        

               |   [ 6,  7, 12, 14],
               v  
      |            [ 0, 15,  0, 20],
      v
                   [18, 21, 24, 28]])
```

Hence, the permuted order needed is `(2,0,3,1)` :

```
In [275]: a.transpose((2, 0, 3, 1))
Out[275]: 
array([[[[ 0,  5],
         [ 0, 10]],

        [[ 6,  7],
         [12, 14]]],


       [[[ 0, 15],
         [ 0, 20]],

        [[18, 21],
         [24, 28]]]])
```

Then, simply reshape to the expected shape :

```
In [276]: a.transpose((2, 0, 3, 1)).reshape(4,4)
Out[276]: 
array([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
       [ 6,  7, 12, 14],
       [ 0, 15,  0, 20],
       [18, 21, 24, 28]])
```

---

**More examples**

I dug up my history and found few `Q&As` based on `nd` to `nd` transformations. These could serve as other example cases, albeit with lesser explanation (mostly). As mentioned earlier, at most two `reshapes` and at most one `swapaxes`/`transpose` did the job everywhere. They are listed below :

- [Python Reshape 3d array into 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211988/python-reshape-3d-array-into-2d)
- [reshape an array using python/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562853/reshape-an-array-using-python-numpy)
- [Merging non-overlapping array blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510395/merging-non-overlapping-array-blocks)
- [Conversion from a Numpy 3D array to a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652082/conversion-from-a-numpy-3d-array-to-a-2d-array)
- [how to reshape an N length vector to a 3x(N/3) matrix in numpy using reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477945/how-to-reshape-an-n-length-vector-to-a-3xn-3-matrix-in-numpy-using-reshape)
- [Construct image from 4D list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718234/construct-image-from-4d-list)
- [Reshaping/Combining several sub-matrices to one matrix in multi-dimensional space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606602/reshaping-combining-several-sub-matrices-to-one-matrix-in-multi-dimensional-spac)
- [Interlace various small 2D matrices into a bigger one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892382/interlace-various-small-2d-matrices-into-a-bigger-one)
- [how to retrieve every section by 3X3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499475/how-to-retrieve-every-section-by-3x3)
- [Reshaping 3D Numpy Array to a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547453/reshaping-3d-numpy-array-to-a-2d-array)
- [Iterate in submatrices through a bigger matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812918/iterate-in-submatrices-through-a-bigger-matrix)
- [Reorganizing a 2D numpy array into 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513420/reorganizing-a-2d-numpy-array-into-3d)
- [Numpy change shape from (3, 512, 660, 4) to (3,2048,660,1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388237/numpy-change-shape-from-3-512-660-4-to-3-2048-660-1)
- [Numpy: rotate sub matrix m of M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234839/numpy-rotate-sub-matrix-m-of-m)
- [Split a 3D numpy array into 3D blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429900/split-a-3d-numpy-array-into-3d-blocks)
- [Converting 3D matrix to cascaded 2D Matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525345/converting-3d-matrix-to-cascaded-2d-matrices)
- [Rearranging numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943700/rearranging-numpy-array)
- [Numpy: Reshape array along a specified axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929531/numpy-reshape-array-along-a-specified-axis)
- [How to construct 2d array from 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166662/how-to-construct-2d-array-from-2d-arrays)
- [How to form a matrix from submatrices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719889/how-to-form-a-matrix-from-submatrices)
- [Python: Reshape 3D image series to pixel series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092774/python-reshape-3d-image-series-to-pixel-series)

Answer (score 11):

It seems like you're looking for a [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) followed by a [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

```
x.transpose((2, 0, 3, 1)).reshape(np.prod(x.shape[:2]), -1)

array([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
       [ 6,  7, 12, 14],
       [ 0, 15,  0, 20],
       [18, 21, 24, 28]])
```

---

To help you understand why a transposition is needed, let's analyse your incorrectly shaped output (obtained by a single `reshape` call) to *understand* why it is incorrect.

A simple 2D reshaped version of this result (without any transposition) looks like this -

```
x.reshape(4, 4)

array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5, 10, 15, 20],
       [ 6, 12, 18, 24],
       [ 7, 14, 21, 28]])
```

Now consider this output with respect to your expected output -

```
array([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
       [ 6,  7, 12, 14],
       [ 0, 15,  0, 20],
       [18, 21, 24, 28]])
```

You'll notice that your actual result is obtained by a Z-like traversal of your incorrectly shaped output -

```
start
    | /|     /| /|
    |/ |    / |/ |
      /    /    / 
     /    /    /
    | /| /    | /|
    |/ |/     |/ |
                 end
```

This implies that you must move over the array in varying strides to get your *actual* result. In conclusion, a simple reshape is not enough. You must *transpose* the original array, in such a manner that these Z-like elements are made to be contiguous to each other, such that a subsequent reshape call gives you the output you need.

To understand how to transpose correctly, you should trace the elements along the input and figure out what axes you need to jump to get to each one in the output. The transposition follows accordingly. [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/4909087) does a sterling job of explaining this.

Comment: ... or just flip it during the transpose ><

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why'd you delete? It looked right.

Comment: Because it is definitely more elegant to just `.transpose(2, 0, 3, 1)` instead of `.transpose(0,2,1,3)` and *then* reshape, taking the array in fortran-order...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks! So, there's isn't a straightforward way to do it using only `reshape` without `np.prod` et al?

Comment: @kmario23 Unfortunately not. `reshape` only changes the view (number of dimensions). Judging by your input and expected output, you required a transposition, rather than a simple reshape.

Comment: @kmario23 Hmm, I've added some explanation, I hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Needed to use your solution to explain for a generic case. Hope that's okay.

Comment: @Divakar No problems at all. Thanks for weighing in with your expertise :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm accepting Divakar's answer since it's much more straightforward and simple. But, your explanations are good as well!

Comment: @kmario23 No problem. My explanation follows a different angle from Divakar's, because I wanted to correct your misconception that a simple reshape was enough. For this purpose, I went with analysing the incorrectly reshaped output rather than the original input. I have no complaints with the acceptance, his answer is gold standard.

Answer (score 0):

[The Divarkar's answer is great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977238/intuition-and-idea-behind-reshaping-4d-array-to-2d-array-in-numpy/47978032#47978032), though sometimes it is easier for me just to check all possible cases which `transpose` and `reshape` cover.

For example, the following code

```
n, m = 4, 2
arr = np.arange(n*n*m*m).reshape(n,n,m,m)
for permut in itertools.permutations(range(4)):
    arr2 = (arr.transpose(permut)).reshape(n*m, n*m)
    print(permut, arr2[0])
```

gives me all what one can get from 4-dimensional array using `transpose` + `reshape`. Since, I know how the output should look like, I will just pick the permutation that showed me the correct answer. If I didn't get what I wanted, then `transpose` + `reshape` is not general enough to cover my case and I have to do something more complicated.