# How to reshape an matrix of grayscale images in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix of images with shape (50, 17500). Each image has shape (50, 50), so my matrix is like a long row of 350 grayscale images.

I want to use `plt.imshow()` to display those images. How do I change the dimension of the concatenated images matrix? Say reshaping the array to shape (1750, 500), which is 35 rows and 10 columns of images.

Some posts suggest to use `np.reshape()`, but if I use `my_array.reshape((1750, 500))` the individual image in the new matrix is broken.

My question is how to reshape while preserving each individual (50,50) image?

Comment: Would depend on how the images are stored in each row. But, for a general theory on such transformations, follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977238/intuition-and-idea-behind-reshaping-4d-array-to-2d-array-in-numpy

Comment: something like `np.concatenate(np.split(a, 35, axis=1))`, if efficiency (memory for copies) isn't important ?