# Tips or patterns for reshaping 4D/5D arrays, (videos to frames)

Tags: numpy, reshape, pytorch

I find it really hard to visualize reshaping 4D 5D arrays in numpy/pytorch. (I assume both reshape in similar patter, I am using pytorch currently!).

Like suppose I have videos with dimension [N x C x D x H x W]

(***num videos*** x ***channels video*** x ***frames video*** x ***height video*** x ***width video***)

Suppose I want to reshape video into frames as [N x C x H x W], how should I proceed in reshape.

Simple applying `x = x.reshape(N*D, C, H, W)` doesn't actually do it, it gives wrong order of elements.

Can you help me with how to do this, and any slight of intuition of pattern you used?

> On a sidenote, if i have one video (i.e suppose 1x3x100x256x256 I use :
>
> the following code approach:
>
> `x = x.squeeze(0).T.reshape((100,3,256,256))[:,:,None,:,:]` and it works
>
> great. Couldnt figure out for more than 1 video.

Thanks!

As per the request :

```
input = np.random.randn(N,C,D,H,W)
output = np.zeros((N*D,C,H,W))
```

As per the request, a for loop based code to show what I want

`for h in range(N):
    for i in range(D):
        for j in range(C):
            for k in range(H):
                for l in range(W):
                    output[h*D + i,j,k,l] = input[h,j,i,k,l]`

Comment: Could you show a working loopy code? Perhaps with `x.squeeze(0).T.reshape((100,3,256,256))[:,:,None,:,:]` that stores into an output array?

Comment: Ahh you mean reshape via for loops??

Comment: Yes, a working solution code using loops, just so that we have a reference to work with.

Comment: @Divakar  here you go :), it might be slightly incorrect indexing wise, will check, but you'll get what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply swap the second and third axes, and then merge the new second axis (old third one) with the first one with reshaping -

```
output = input_array.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(N*D,C,H,W)
```

We can also use `transpose` : `input_array.transpose(0,2,1,3,4)` to get the same swapping axes effect.

For a general intuitive method, please refer to [Intuition and idea behind reshaping 4D array to 2D array in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977238/intuition-and-idea-behind-reshaping-4d-array-to-2d-array-in-numpy).

Comment: So in such kind of operation 5D to 4D, reshaping i should permute axes to get them adjacent and then reshape?

Comment: Also I thought about it, but I just dont get it intuitively, like need to check for dummy values. Any thing you know that helps or anything intuition or some references (for high dimension array operations)

Comment: That looks epic! Thanks, just what I was looking for :)