# PyTorch reshepe 4d to 2d, with "with saving 1 dim"

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Have a tensor X:

`X.shape = [2, 3, 4, 5]`

```
This tensor represents pictures.
X[0] - number of pic.
X[1] -  Chanels
X[2],X[3] -  Height and Width.
```

I want to convert this tensor to shape [40,2] where second dim is 3 channels, and first all pixels in input data, which correspond channels in right order.
try to use

```
reshape(-1,3)
```

but chanels are in incorrect order.
How i can convert it?
It is also interesting how i can to convert back, from [40,2] to [2,3,4,5]

### **SOLUTION**

Find solution fo my case:

```
x.permute(1,0,2,3).reshape(3,-1).T
```

from this X: 
       [image]

to this X: [image]

Comment: [40,2] or [40,3] for the second one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tips or patterns for reshaping 4D/5D arrays, (videos to frames)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502700/tips-or-patterns-for-reshaping-4d-5d-arrays-videos-to-frames)

Comment: What is the right order?

Comment: @like444 Yes. [40,2]. Fixed it.