# Reshaping a three-dimensional ndarray into two dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have a three-dimensional array (shape is 2,2,3), which can be thought of as a combination of two two-dimensional arrays. I'd like to get these two arrays and put them side-by-side. Here's my starting point:

```
test1 = np.ndarray((2,2,3))
test1[0] = np.array([[1,2,3],
                     [4,5,6]])
test1[1] = np.array([[7,8,9],
                     [10,11,12]])
```

I can get to the desired result by iterating through the first dimension, likeso:

```
output = np.ndarray((2,6))
for n_port, port in enumerate(test1):
    output[:,n_port*3:(n_port+1)*3] = port
```

which gives:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6., 10., 11., 12.]])
```

But I'm wondering if there's a slicker way to do it. The reshape function would be the obvious way to go but it flattens them out, rather than stacking them side-by-side:

```
test1.reshape((2,6))
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.]])
```

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `swapaxes()` first, then `reshape()`:

```
test1.swapaxes(0,1).reshape(2,6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the backtracking idea described in the thread: [intuition and idea behind reshaping 4D array to 2D array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977238/intuition-and-idea-behind-reshaping-4d-array-to-2d-array-in-numpy), you can use a combination of `arr.transpose` and `arr.reshape` as in:

```
In [162]: dd = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(2, 2, 3)

In [163]: dd
Out[163]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])

In [164]: dd.transpose((1, 0, 2))
Out[164]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6],
        [10, 11, 12]]])

In [165]: dd.transpose((1, 0, 2)).reshape(2, -1)
Out[165]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12]])
```