# numpy's hstack on tensorflow for a single matrix/tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, concatenation

The numpy version of hstack for a single matrix

```
c=np.array([[[2,3,4],[4,5,6]],[[20,30,40],[40,50,60]]])

np.hstack(c)
```

output:

```
array([[ 2,  3,  4, 20, 30, 40],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 40, 50, 60]])
```

I am hoping to achieve the same behavior in TF.

```
c_t=tf.constant(c)
tf.stack(c_t,axis=1).eval()
```

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: Expected list for 'values' argument to 'pack' Op, not <tf.Tensor 'Const_14:0' shape=(2, 2, 3) dtype=int64>.
```

So I tried

```
tf.stack([c_t],axis=1).eval()
```

The output

```
array([[[[ 2,  3,  4],
         [ 4,  5,  6]]],


       [[[20, 30, 40],
         [40, 50, 60]]]])
```

I am not looking for the behaviour. `tf.reshape` and `tf.concat` are not helping me either.

Comment: `np.hstack` treats `c` as a list of 2 (2,3) arrays.  In fact it starts with a list comprehension on the argument, `[atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it work is first unstack the tensor into a list, and then concatenate the tensors in list on first axis:

```
new_c = tf.concat(tf.unstack(c_t), axis=1)
sess.run(new_c)

array([[ 2,  3,  4, 20, 30, 40],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 40, 50, 60]])
```

Comment: Split into two tensors and concat. Nice answer!

Comment: You should mention caveat with `tf.unstack`. It will not accept dynamic size.  I can not give matrix of size (-1,2,3). -1 will throw `tf.unstack` off.

Answer (score 2):

We can swap/permute axes and reshape -

```
tf.reshape(tf.transpose(c_t,(1,0,2)),(c_t.shape[1],-1))
```

Relevant - [Intuition and idea behind reshaping 4D array to 2D array in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977238/intuition-and-idea-behind-reshaping-4d-array-to-2d-array-in-numpy)

Comment: A programmer needs to keep track of so many axes. I will accept the previous answer for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the manual way at the atomic level, then the below approach would as well work.

```
In [132]: c=np.array([[[2,3,4],[4,5,6]],[[20,30,40],[40,50,60]]])
In [133]: tfc = tf.convert_to_tensor(c) 

In [134]: slices = [tf.squeeze(tfc[:1, ...]), tf.squeeze(tfc[1:, ...])]  
In [135]: stacked = tf.concat(slices, axis=1) 
In [136]: stacked.eval()           
Out[136]: 
array([[ 2,  3,  4, 20, 30, 40],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 40, 50, 60]])
```