# Reverse stacking operation on NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, reshape

I'm have a line of code that efficiently reshapes a numpy array from a 400x8x8 array to a 160x160 array and I need to reverse the process but can't figure out the reverse of the line.

I can already do this process but it is very inefficient and requires nested loops which I would like to avoid for performance purposes.

Here is the code that I currently have to reverse the process (160x160 > 400x8x8):

```
       previousRow = 0
    for rowBlock in range(noBlocksOn1Axis):
        previousRow = rowBlock * blockSize  
        previousColumn = 0
        for columnBlock in range(noBlocksOn1Axis):
            previousColumn = columnBlock * blockSize
            block = 
            arrayY[previousRow:previousRow+blockSize, 
            previousColumn:previousColumn + blockSize]
            blocksList.append(block)
```

And here is the line of code that reshapes 400x8x8 > 160x160:

```
    xy = np.zeros((160,160), dtype = np.uint8)

    xy = np.vstack(np.hstack(overDone[20*i:20+20*i]) for i in 
    range(overDone.shape[0]//20))
```

So any ideas of how I can perform this line of code in reverse?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape, swap-axes (or transpose axes) and reshape to get `overDone` back -

```
xy.reshape(20,8,20,8).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(400,8,8)
```

More info on [`intuition behind nd-to-nd array transformation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/3293881).

Make it generic to handle generic shapes -

```
m,n = xy.shape
M,N = 20,20 # block size used to get xy
overDone_ = xy.reshape(M,m//M,N,n//N).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,m//M,n//N)
```

Sample run -

```
# Original input
In [21]: overDone = np.random.rand(400,8,8)

# Perform forward step to get xy
In [22]: xy = np.vstack(np.hstack(overDone[20*i:20+20*i]) for i in range(overDone.shape[0]//20))

# Use proposed approach to get back overDone
In [23]: out = xy.reshape(20,8,20,8).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(400,8,8)

# Verify output to be same as overDone
In [42]: np.array_equal(out,overDone)
Out[42]: True
```

Bonus :

We could use those same vectorized `reshape+permute-axes` steps to create `xy` for the forward process -

```
xy = overDone.reshape(20,20,8,8).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(160,160)
```

Comment: You should show the more efficient way to do the forward operation here too

Comment: @Eric Good idea! Added.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)?

```
my_array_3d = my_array.reshape((400, 8, 8))
my_array_2d = my_array.reshape((160, 160))
```