# How to reshape this array the way I need?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I'm looking to reshape an array of three 2x2 matrices, that is of shape (3,2,2) i.e.

```
a = np.array([[[a1,a2],[a3,a4]],
             [[b1,b2],[b3,b4]],
             [[c1,c2],[c3,c4]]])
```

to this array of shape (2,2,3):

```
[[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2]],
 [[a3,b3,c3],[a4,b4,c4]]])
```

The regular `np.reshape(a, (2,2,3))` returns this array:

```
[[[a1, a2, a3],[a4, b1, b2]],
 [[b3, b4, c1],[c2, c3, c4]]]
```

and `np.reshape(a, (2,2,3), order = 'F')` brings this:

```
[[[a1, b3, c2],[c1, a2, b4]],
 [[b1, c3, a4],[a3, b2, c4]]]
```

How can I reshape the initial array to get what I need?

This is in order to use with `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` where the three initial matrices correspond to the three colors 'RGB' and each of the elements is a float in the range [0,1]. So also if there's a better way to do it I would be happy to know.

Comment: look at `transpose(order)`. you may have to try a couple of variations,

Comment: More explanation can be found at [nD-nD transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47977238/2956066)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simply need to permute axes. Two ways to do so.

Use `np.transpose` -

```
a.transpose(1,2,0) # a is input array
# or np.transpose(a,(1,2,0))
```

We can also use `np.moveaxis` -

```
np.moveaxis(a,0,2)    # np.moveaxis(a, 0, -1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [157]: np.random.seed(0)

In [158]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(3,2,2))

In [159]: a
Out[159]: 
array([[[55, 58],
        [75, 78]],

       [[78, 20],
        [94, 32]],

       [[47, 98],
        [81, 23]]])

In [160]: a.transpose(1,2,0)
Out[160]: 
array([[[55, 78, 47],
        [58, 20, 98]],

       [[75, 94, 81],
        [78, 32, 23]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the *transpose*:

```
a = np.array([[['a1', 'a2'],['a3', 'a4']],
             [['b1', 'b2'],['b3', 'b4']],
             [['c1', 'c2'],['c3', 'c4']]])

print(np.rollaxis(a, 1, 3).T)
```

Output:

```
[[['a1' 'b1' 'c1']
  ['a2' 'b2' 'c2']]

 [['a3' 'b3' 'c3']
  ['a4' 'b4' 'c4']]]
```