# Numpy specific reshape order for 2D Array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, reshape

I've got a 4x3 matrix and I need to reshape it to a 2x6 matrix with a specific order:

Initial : 
|1   5   9|
|2   6  10|
|3   7  11|
|4   8  12|

Wanted :
|1  2  5  6   9  10|
|3  4  7  8  11  12|

I tried tu use numpy but the order was not what I expected :

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,5,9],[2,6,10],[3,17,11],[4,8,12]])
b=a.reshape(2,6)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you? Consider accepting it? More info on what it means to accept and how to - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Reshape, permute and reshape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/) -

```
In [51]: n = 2 # no. of rows to select from input to form each row of output

In [52]: a.reshape(-1,n,a.shape[1]).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,n*a.shape[1])
Out[52]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10],
       [ 3,  4, 17,  8, 11, 12]])
```

Sort of an explanation :

1. Cut along the first axis to end up with `3D` array such that we select `n` along the second one. Swap this second axis with the last(third) axis, so that we *push back* that second one to the end.
2. Reshape to `2D` to merge the last two axes. That's our output!

For more in-depth info, please refer to the linked Q&A.

---

If we are given the number of rows in output -

```
In [54]: nrows = 2 # number of rows in output

In [55]: a.reshape(nrows,-1,a.shape[1]).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(nrows,-1)
Out[55]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10],
       [ 3,  4, 17,  8, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: Can you avoid the `swapaxes` with `order='F'` for the final reshape?  `a.reshape(-1,n,a.shape[1]).reshape(-1,n*a.shape[1], order='F')`

Comment: @user3483203 Nope, we can't. That ravel('F') changes the entire order.

Comment: Great! can you explain please because I want to tranpose your solution to a 8x3 => 2x12 Matrix. [[ 1  9 17]
 [ 2 10 18]
 [ 3 11 19]
 [ 4 12 20]
 [ 5 13 21]
 [ 6 14 22]
 [ 7 15 23]
 [ 8 16 24]] =>
[[ 1  9 17  2 10 18  3 11 19  4 12 20]
 [ 5 13 21  6 14 22  7 15 23  8 16 24]]

Comment: @Divakar, I'm sorry missed you link!

Comment: @Divakar, got it : 

import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1,9,17],[2,10,18],[3,11,19],[4,12,20],[5,13,21],[6,14,22],[7,15,23],[8,16,24]])
b=a.reshape(-1,4,a.shape[1]).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,4*a.shape[1])
print(a)
print(b)

Comment: @user3483203 That works! Consider positing that one. I am skeptical about using ravel('F')  though for memory and perf. I need to test out on that to actual make any conclusions though.

Comment: I had assumed (incorrectly I think) that swap axes was going to be more overhead than the different re-ordering.  I did some timing on larger arrays and the swapaxes always seems to be faster.

Comment: @user3483203 Which makes sense. `Ravel('F')` changes orders across all axes. So, basically it's `transpose(2,1,0)` and then reshape, while we can simply do - `swapaxes(1,2)` here i.e. re-order only 2 axes. To time it out, consider a 3D array and time - `a.transpose(2,1,0).copy()` and `a.swapaxes(1,2).copy()`.