# Flatten np.ndarray in customized order

Tags: python, numpy

I have a np.ndarray with the shape (24, 3). I want to flatten this array but in a rathor unusual way. I would like to have [0:8, 0] then [0:8, 1] then [0:8, 2] then [8:16, 0] and so on.

Of course i could do it the brute force way but maybe there is a more elegant and efficient solution to this problem.

```py
new_array = np.array([])
np.append(new_array, old_array[0:8, 0])
np.append(new_array, old_array[0:8, 1])
np.append(new_array, old_array[0:8, 2])

np.append(new_array, old_array[8:16, 0])
np.append(new_array, old_array[8:16, 1])
np.append(new_array, old_array[8:16, 2])

np.append(new_array, old_array[16:24, 0])
np.append(new_array, old_array[16:24, 1])
np.append(new_array, old_array[16:24, 2])
```

Comment: Use `old_array.ravel('F')`.

Comment: Hmm not sure @divakar I think reshape is needed first

Comment: Does this do what you want `np.array(np.array_split(a, 3)).swapaxes(1,2).ravel()`?

Comment: @yatu Good call. Reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Reshape, permute and reshape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/) -

```
n = 8 # cut length along first axis
new_array = old_array.reshape(-1,n,old_array.shape[1]).swapaxes(1,2).ravel()
```