# Flatten or group array in blocks of columns - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy, flatten

Is there any easy way to flatten

```
import numpy    
np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
Out[]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

into

```
array([ 0,  1,  4,  5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11])
```

Comment: `arr.reshape(3, 2, 2).swapaxes(0, 1).ravel()` will do, but without the expected logic, it is hard to say if it is what you are after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are looking to consider a specific number of cols to form blocks and then getting the elements in each block and then moving onto the next ones. So, with that in mind, here's one way -

```
In [148]: a
Out[148]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [149]: ncols = 2 # no. of cols to be considered for each block

In [150]: a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1,ncols).swapaxes(0,1).ravel()
Out[150]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  9,  2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11])
```

The motivation behind is discussed in detail in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/).

Additionally, to keep the 2D format -

```
In [27]: a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1,ncols).swapaxes(0,1).reshape(-1,ncols)
Out[27]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])
```

And to have it in a *intuitive* 3D array format -

```
In [28]: a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1,ncols).swapaxes(0,1)
Out[28]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 8,  9]],

       [[ 2,  3],
        [ 6,  7],
        [10, 11]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

For this I'd simply slice and [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
n = a.shape[1]//2
np.concatenate([a[:,:n], a[:,n:]]).ravel()
# array([ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  9,  2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to slice the array into blocks and then use the [`numpy.ndarray.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) method to flatten the blocks into a 1D array (this will only work if `a.shape[1]` is divisible by the block size `n`):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)

n = 2

res = np.array([a[:, i : i + n] for i in range(0, a.shape[1], n)]).flatten()

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  1  4  5  8  9  2  3  6  7 10 11 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
first_list = [entry[0:2] for entry in a]
second_list = [entry[2:4] for entry in a]
flat_list = [item for sublist in first_list for item in sublist] + [item for sublist in second_list for item in sublist]

flat_list # [0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that doesn't involve numpy if you want, and it will take care for every kind of array you'll get,

```
[[12312],[],[[]]] 
[[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]]
[-1, [1, [-2], 1], -1]
etc
```

First option(won't work for **strings**)

```
def flat_list(array):
    return list(flatten(array))              
def flatten(nested): 
    try:
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested
```

**Second option:**

```
def flatten(nested): #in case you got strings and you want to avoide an infinite recursion
    try:
        # Don't iterate over string-like objects:
        try: nested + ''
        except TypeError: pass
        else: raise TypeError
        for sublist in nested:
            for element in flatten(sublist):
                yield element
    except TypeError:
        yield nested
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using numpy here. It has a method to do exactly what you want.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
flat = arr.flatten()
```

Another approach:

```
a = []
[a.extend(x) for x in arr]
```

Comment: You are ignoring the desired pattern.