# Rearrange image in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to load an image file in tif format and rearrange it into a long strip but preserve the horizontal order. When I have tried to use numpy reshape it just overlays the different rows onto each other or corrupts the image.
Say I have an array like this

```
imagearray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
             [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

I want to rearrange it so that it looks like this

```
[1,2],
[0,0],
[1,1],
[2,2],
[3,4],
[0,0],
[1,1],
[2,2]
```

and so on. My issue is keeping that order as I rearrange it without using any more memory as these are 3GB images using reshape or rearrange are ways that I can use less memory. I think that it is more difficult also because the image technically has shape (n,m,3) which I don't fully understand how to manipulate. [this is what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMoZ3.jpg) from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVWV5.png) when it is supposed to look more similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAOw0.jpg)

This is the basics of the file that I am using

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
width =  4000
height = 4000
rollwidth = 1000
I = cv2.imread("image path")
print("read image")
resizedImage = cv2.resize(I,(height,width), interpolation= cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
print("combined done")
testimage = np.reshape(resizedImage,((np.ceil(width/rollwidth).astype(np.int64)*height),rollwidth,3), order ='C')
cv2.imwrite("save path", testimage)
print("done")
```

I think that this is slightly different to the duplicate flag as using the proposed steps I still can't get the needed result

Comment: From the linked Q&A's accepted answer, replace `.ravel()` with `.reshape(-1,2)`.

Comment: doesnt look like it works for me with images. if you tried it with an image you might see my issue but say I wanted the image to be 16000 high and 1000 wide would I have to use it like this?

testimage = np.reshape(image,(16000,1000,3),rollwidth).reshape(-1,1000)

Comment: Why are you skipping `swapaxes`? Think it would be - `a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1,ncols).swapaxes(0,1).reshape(-1,ncols)` with `a` being the input array. Also, isn't your input a 2D array?

Comment: because it is an image it has (n,m,3) shape

Comment: Please add a minimal representative for your 3D array case and expected output.

Comment: OK, I am struggling to visualise this as a 3d array but I assumer that the 3 depth layer is the rgb values, I am expecting z for newx, newy to equal the z for originalx,originaly. before moving it. I don't know how I would represent this exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101340/), we will simply extend it to 3D case keeping in mind that we need to *split-up* the second axis, while keeping the third axis (color channel one) as it is -

```
# a is input 3D array
# ncols would be the width of the desired output image
m,n,r = a.shape
b = a.reshape(m,-1,ncols,r).swapaxes(0,1).reshape(-1,ncols,r)
```

The motivation behind is discussed in detail in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/).

Comment: @Dominic.New.Work Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I think this might be what I needed, going to test it with one of my full-sized images now and see if it works then I'll mark this as the answer