# Split and Swap Items in Nth Dimension to Nth+1 Dimension

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I had a numpy array like this:

```
[[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
  [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
  [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16]]]
```

Which has the dimensions of (1, 4, 4)

and I wanted to convert it to:

```
[[[[ 1,  3], [ 2,  4]],
  [[ 5,  7], [ 6,  8]],
  [[ 9, 11], [10, 12]],
  [[13, 15], [14, 16]]]]
```

Which has the dimensions of (1, 4, 2, 2).

Is there any function within numpy which I could use to modify the array as such?

- array.reshape() is close, but not entirely because it cannot swap items.

I want to avoid using straight python as this code is being used to format some data for a neural network input, and the speed of python (given the size of the actual arrays are) is likely to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. The only thing you need to do is then swap the third and the fourth axis:

```
>>> np.swapaxes(a.reshape(1,4,2,2), 2,3)
array([[[[ 1,  3],
         [ 2,  4]],

        [[ 5,  7],
         [ 6,  8]],

        [[ 9, 11],
         [10, 12]],

        [[13, 15],
         [14, 16]]]])
```

Comment: Though this answer directly solves my issue, Divakar's answer is more generic and likely to be significantly more useful for people who are reading this question.

Answer (score 1):

Split the last axis, then permute axes -

```
In [41]: a
Out[41]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]]])

In [42]: a.reshape(-1,2,2).swapaxes(1,2)
Out[42]: 
array([[[ 1,  3],
        [ 2,  4]],

       [[ 5,  7],
        [ 6,  8]],

       [[ 9, 11],
        [10, 12]],

       [[13, 15],
        [14, 16]]])
```

If you need the final output shape to be `(1,4,2,2)`, add a new axis at the front with `None/np.newaxis` -

```
In [43]: a.reshape(-1,2,2).swapaxes(1,2)[None]
Out[43]: 
array([[[[ 1,  3],
         [ 2,  4]],

        [[ 5,  7],
         [ 6,  8]],

        [[ 9, 11],
         [10, 12]],

        [[13, 15],
         [14, 16]]]])

In [44]: _.shape
Out[44]: (1, 4, 2, 2)
```

For a generic case with the number of elements per list being known, say `n`, it would be -

```
a.reshape(-1,n,a.shape[-1]//n).swapaxes(1,2)[None]
```

[`More info on`nd-arrays`transformation.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask reshape to use FORTRAN order:

```
a = np.arange(1,17).reshape(1,4,4)

a.reshape(*a.shape[:-1],2,2,order="F")
# array([[[[ 1,  3],
#          [ 2,  4]],
# 
#         [[ 5,  7],
#          [ 6,  8]],
# 
#         [[ 9, 11],
#          [10, 12]],
# 
#         [[13, 15],
#          [14, 16]]]])
```