# Numpy: function to create block matrix from another matrices, each block should contain values from the same indexes from another matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm looking for some fast function to create blocks in matrix from another matrices like in a picture (bottom matrix is result):
[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjP9V.jpg)

I also wrote some code to do this but for many matrices is working slow.

```
import numpy as np
im1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
im2 = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
im3 = np.array([[9, 10], [11, 12]])
im4 = np.array([[13, 14], [15, 15]])
arrays = [im1, im2, im3, im4]


def array_rearrangement(arrays):
    num = int(len(arrays) ** 0.5)
    size = arrays[0].shape[0] * num

    result = np.zeros((size, size))
    k = -1
    p = -1
    for k1 in range(num * num):
        if k1 % num == 0:
            k = 0
        if k1 % num == 0:
            p += 1
        im = arrays[k1]
        for i in range(num):
            for j in range(num):
                x_index = i * num + p
                y_index = j * num + k
                result[x_index, y_index] = im[i, j]

        k += 1

    print(result)


array_rearrangement(arrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977238/intuition-and-idea-behind-reshaping-4d-array-to-2d-array-in-numpy) is always a good starting point for `nd` to `nd` transformation.  In your case, this is a `reshape`, `swapaxes` and `reshape` again.

---

```
arr = np.column_stack(arrays)
arr.reshape(-1, 2, 2).swapaxes(2, 1).reshape(4, 4)
```

```
array([[ 1,  5,  2,  6],
       [ 9, 13, 10, 14],
       [ 3,  7,  4,  8],
       [11, 15, 12, 15]])
```