# Easy way to fold a multidimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy 2D array:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
```

where each column of this array (i.e.: `[1,3, 5, 7]`, and `[2, 4, 6, 8]`) need to be transformed to a matrix of given size `M1xM2` (using order='F' when reshaping). In this case, `M1 = M2 = 2`. So, my desired output would be:

```
b = np.array([[[1, 5], [3, 7]], [[2, 6], [4, 8]]]).
```

I can easily achieve this by iterating over the columns. However, the number of columns can be any and the initial 2D array can be of up to 8 dimensions. How can I easily extend this solution to be used for more dimensions?

I suspect this is a common procedure and there is a built-in function to solve it, but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: What do you mean "up to 8 dimensions"? Can you give examples of these higher dimensional arrays?

Comment: @Daniela - I also would like to try to solve this in higher dimensions (perhaps in another question), but I'm not completely shure what an example would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as reshape, then transpose:

```
a.reshape(2, 2, -1).T
# array([[[1, 5],
#         [3, 7]],
# 
#        [[2, 6],
#         [4, 8]]])
```

Comment: I had to add order='F' in my case, but this answer worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reshape`, `swapaxes`, `reshape`. [@divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) posted a detailed [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977238/intuition-and-idea-behind-reshaping-4d-array-to-2d-array-in-numpy/47978032#47978032).

```
a.T.reshape(2,2,2,1).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(2,2,-1)
```

Out:

```
array([[[1, 5],
        [3, 7]],

       [[2, 6],
        [4, 8]]])
```

Comment: You can simplify it to `a.reshape(2, 2, -1).transpose(2, 1, 0)`

Comment: Yes that's true, but for me it's hard to find that solution. I memorized the pattern in my answer. Can you post your solution as an answer?