# Numpy reorganize array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have got the following numpy array

```
A = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19],[20,21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28,29]])

out[]: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

I would like to reorganize it in such a way that the output is

```
out[] : array([[0,5],
         [1,6],
         [2,7],
         [3,8],
         [4,9],
         [10,15],
         [11,16],
         [12,17],
         [13,18],
         [14,19],
         [20,25],
         [21,26],
         ....,
         [24,29]])
```

I have been trying different combinations of `np.reshape`, `tranpose`, `flatten`, `np.swapaxes`, but with no success.

The real array has tens or sometimes hundreds of rows.

Originally, the data is given as DataFrame, but I realized that converting to `numpy` array could be a better alternative... Can it be done directly using pandas?

Comment: `A.reshape(-1, 2, 5).transpose(0, 2, 1).reshape(-1, 2)`?

Comment: So the first, third, etc. row should be the first column and the second, fourth, etc. row should be the second column?

Comment: Yes, in general for a, let's say 100x5 dimensional array, I would like to group every 10 rows and put them as columns (this subgroup would be 5x10), then the 10 subgroups are later appended,  such that I end up with a 50x10 dimensional array

Comment: @KelvinTitimbo You can refer this answer for  general logic to solve these kind of problems https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/5462372

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done in this way using `as_strided`.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

A = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19],[20,21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28,29]])
A = A.reshape(3, 2, 5)
#print(A)
S = A.itemsize
out = as_strided(A, shape=(3,5,2), strides=(2*A.shape[1]*S ,S, A.shape[1]*S)).copy()
out = out.reshape(15,2)
print(out)
>> [[ 0  5]
 [ 1  6]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]
 [ 4  9]
 [10 15]
 [11 16]
 [12 17]
 [13 18]
 [14 19]
 [20 25]
 [21 26]
 [22 27]
 [23 28]
 [24 29]]
```